# I included a php file in other and that other file in some other file and all the files are in different directories

Tags: php, filepath

I have `(/navigation/navigation.php)` , `(/menu/whtuto.php)` , `(/submenu/wh/1.php)`

`navigation.php` is included in `whtuto.php` `(../navigation/navigation.php)`
and
whtuto.php is included in `1.php` `(../../menu/whtuto.php)`

But when I load 1.php it gives error!

```
 Warning: include(../navigation/navigation.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\hackingtuto\menupages\whtuto.php on line 3

Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0011  364600  {main}( )   ..\11.php:0
2   0.0021  366824  include( 'C:\wamp\www\hackingtuto\menupages\whtuto.php' )   ..\11.php:3


Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '../navigation/navigation.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\hackingtuto\menupages\whtuto.php on line 3

Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0011  364600  {main}( )   ..\11.php:0
2   0.0021  366824  include( 'C:\wamp\www\hackingtuto\menupages\whtuto.php' )
```

Comment: To help future requests, it is recommended that you accept an answer. Psst, little hint -- it gives you some reputation to accept an answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have used nested includes. It will find the relative path from the first php file executed.

To avoid this problem use

```
include (realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/folder_name/myfile.php"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Includes are relative to the current working directory, which is the directory the first script is started from. You can get the directory of the current include file using the PHP magic variable `__DIR__`, so you can make your includes relative to that instead - e.g. in whtuto.php you should use `include(__DIR__."/../navigation/navigation.php")` and so on. Just prepend `__DIR__` to your include paths. You need to add an extra slash at the start too because `__DIR__` doesn't have a trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is :

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; // Have this in every file you call your includes
include($root."/path/to/file.php");
```